# Highscore doesn't count - everytime 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple "Clickgame" which is working very well. What is not working is the highscore which I want to implementate. After the game is finish, the highscore is everytime 0. Someone know where the problem is since im very new to Javascript?

Here the code. Everything is working till the highScore function. Since I'm very new to javascript I can't find the mistake.

```js
let klick = 0;
let timerId = 0;

$("#start").click(function() { //clickfunktion beim starten.
    $("#start").fadeOut();
    $("#welcome").fadeOut();
    $("#time").fadeIn(900);
    $("#clicker").fadeIn();

    var display = document.querySelector('#time'); //referenz auf das Html attribut Time zum anzeigen.
    var dauer = 5;
    startTimer(dauer, display); //legt die zeit fest, und dass die Funktion gestartet wird.
})

function startTimer(dauer, display) {
    let timer = dauer;
    let sekunden;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        sekunden = parseInt(timer); //parseInt gibt eine ganze Zahl zurück
        display.textContent = sekunden; // zeigt sekunden-variable
        --timer; //setzt den timer immer einen herab
        if (timer < 0.00) {
            timer = dauer;
            $("#start").fadeIn();
            $("#welcome").fadeIn();
            $("#time").fadeOut();
            $("#clicker").fadeOut();
            $("#clicker").css("margin-top", "10%");
            $("#clicker").css("margin-left", "50%");

            alert("Sauber du hast " + klick + " klicks in 5 Sekunden geschafft!");
            alert('High Score is ' + highScore());

            klick = 0
            clearInterval(timerId);
        } //wenn timer auf 0 ist, wird alles wieder angezeigt und die Interval-Function beendet
    }, 1000); //zahl gibt an, wie oft die Function pro zeit wiederholt wird. Hier eine Sekunde (1000Millisekunden)
};

$("#clicker").click(function() {
    let zufall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 1 //setzt eine zufällige höhe für den clicker

    klick = klick + 1 //setzt den zähler beim klicken eins hoch
    $("#clicker").css("margin-top", zufall + "%");
    $("#clicker").css("margin-left", zufall + 45 + "%");
})

function highScore(score) {
    var saved = 0;
    try {
        saved = parseFloat(localStorage.highScore);
    } catch (e) {
        saved = 0;
    }
    if (!(typeof score === 'undefined')) {
        try {
            score = parseFloat(score);
        } catch (e) {
            score = 0;
        }
        if (score > saved) {
            saved = score;
            localStorage.highScore = '' + score;
        }
    }
    if (isNaN(saved)) {
        saved = 0;
        localStorage.highScore = '0';
    }
    return saved;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="time"></span>
</div>
<div id="welcome">Willkommen zu unserem Reaktionsspiel! Wenn du bereit bist, klicke auf "Start"</div>
<button id="start" type="button">Start</button>
<button id="clicker" type="button">KLICK</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are not storing click counter to any variable, once user click anywhere you need to store it to somewhere and once game ends you can show it to alert.

Comment: What about missclicks? Than the highscore would also count the missclicks, or did I understand you wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is partly because you never provide the `highScore()` function with a new high score, so it's always set to `0`. Also note that you can use null coercion to provide default values instead of the try/catch blocks. Try this:

```
function startTimer(dauer, display) {
  // code... 
  alert('High Score is ' + highScore(klick));
  // more code... 
}

function highScore(score) {
  var saved = 0;
  saved = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('highScore')) || 0;
  score = parseFloat(score) || 0;

  if (score > saved) {
    saved = score;
    localStorage.setItem('highScore', score);
  }
  return saved;
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5kzmtye/)